# Integral wrt distribution function

Tags: probability-theory

I am reading "Knowing the Odds" and I don't understand what the author is saying, could someone help me explain it?

> Let $X$ be a random variable on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathscr F, \mathcal P)$, with distribution function $F$ and distribution $ \mu$. We know $\mu$ is a probability measure on $R$ and $(R,\mathcal B, \mu)$ is also a probability space, where $\mathcal B$ is the $\sigma$-field of Borel sets.
>
> Let us use $E^{\mu}$ for the expectation on $(R,\mathcal B, \mu)$. Then we define an integral wrt the distribution function:
>   $$ \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty} f(x)dF(x)=E^{\mu}(f) \tag1$$

I just don't understand why $(1)$ holds, it is just a definition or we compute it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a definition, as the author said.

We have a random variable $X: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$. This induces a measure $\mu = \mathbb{P}_X$ on the Borel sets by

$$\mu(A) = \mathbb{P}(X \in A), A \in \mathcal{R}$$

Then $\mu$ is a probability measure and we have a probability space $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{R}, \mu)$. On this space, we have an expectation operator, which we denote by $\mathbb{E}^\mu$. By definition of an expectation on a probability space, we have

$$\mathbb{E}^\mu[f]:= \int_\mathbb{R} f d \mu$$

where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a random variable (here just a measurable function) 
and then we introduce some extra notation

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dF(x) := \int_\mathbb{R} f d \mu$$

Comment: Is the notation $\int x\,\mathrm dF(x)$ same as $\int x\,\mu_F(\mathrm dx)$ ?since $\mu_F((a,b])=F(b)-F(a)$

Comment: Yes, that's the same thing! Indeed, $\mu_F$ is the measure induced by $F$ (and is determined completely by its values on sets of the form $]a,b]$)